# 32-Bit Addition and Subtraction in MASM x86 Assembly

Tags: assembly, x86, masm, x86-16

I'm trying to write a program that adds and subtracts two 32 bit numbers and stores the sum and difference in memory. I don't have any output and just get the result through the debugger.

Here's my code.

```
;---------------------------------------------------------;
;**********************************************************
STACK   SEGMENT   PARA STACK 'STACK'
        DB 64 DUP('STACK')
STACK   ENDS
;**********************************************************
DSEG    SEGMENT   PARA PUBLIC 'DATA'
X1      DD   4967290
X2      DD   4967295
SUM     DD   ?
DIFF    DD ?
DSEG    ENDS
;**********************************************************
;---------------------------------------------------------
CSEG     SEGMENT   PARA PUBLIC 'CODE'
OUR_PROG PROC  FAR
         ASSUME CS:CSEG, DS:DSEG, SS:STACK
;  Set up the stack to contain the proper values 
;  so this program can return to debug.
;  
         PUSH DS           ; Put return seg. addr on stack
         MOV EAX,0         ; Clear a register EAX
         PUSH EAX          ; Put zero return address on stack

;  Initialize the data segment address
         MOV EAX,DSEG      ;Initialize DS
         MOV DS,AX
;  -------------------------------------------------------------
;  Perform the addition
;
         MOV EAX,X1        ; Load 32 bit variable in X1 to reg AX
         MOV EBX,X2        ; Load 32 bit variable in X2 to reg BX
         ADD EAX,EBX       ; Add data in registers AX and BX, store in AX
;  Store the sum in memory
;
         MOV SUM,EAX       ; Store the result at mem loc SUM
;  -------------------------------------------------------------
;  Perform the subtraction
         MOV EAX,X1       ; Reload first word to reg EAX
         CMP EAX,EBX      ; Compare values of X1 and X2 stored in registers EAX and EBX
         JL  .SWAPSUB     ; If EBX is greater than EAX, jump to SWAPSUB
         JL  .NOSWAP      ; If ''                     , jump past other sub section

.SWAPSUB:                 ;Jump point to swap values

         XCHG EAX,BX      ; Swap values of EAX and EBX

.NOSWAP:         
         SUB EAX,EBX      ; Subtract EBX from EAX
         MOV DIFF,EBX     ; Store the result at mem loc DIFF         

         RET              ; Retrurn to DEBUG
OUR_PROG ENDP
CSEG     ENDS
         END OUR_PROG
;**********************************************************
```

I don't know much about Assembly, but I'm using DOSBOX, MASM 5.10 and a linker program to build my code.

The problem I seem to be having is that when I try to build my code, it says that `EAX` and `EBX` are not defined. It also says `Illegal size for operand` for each of my `MOV` calls to `SUM` or `DIFF`.

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong or an easier way to do this? I've been trying to figure it out for several hours now, with little progress.

Thanks!

Comment: Added .386 to the top of my code and it got rid of most of my errors. Only have one warning left of "Operand types must match" on MOV EAX,DSEG. Not sure if this worked or not, as I can't find the output I'm looking for in the registers or the memory during debug.

Comment: Program now infinitely loops... Still clueless.

Comment: If you're running this in the debugger, then you should be able to single-step it and determine where it loops.

Comment: I don't use MASM, but a couple of thoughts: (1) in .SWAPSUB you probably want `XCHG EAX, EBX`, not what you have; (2) right before it, assuming that `jl` is "jump and link", you instead want `jmp` (or its equivalent in MASM); (3) nothing you have shared with us even has a loop, so don't see how there could be any *infinite* loop: you probably just get stuck, and the program doesn't return instead.

Comment: @gnometorule: `JL` == `Jump if Less (signed)`

Answer (score 1):

You can access 32-bit registers in a 16-bit program with the `.386` directive. But it remains a 16-bit program!

Access to the 32-bit registers is done in the machine code by adding an explicit prefix (66h - "operand-size prefix") to the instruction encoding. However, `.386` without using the `.MODEL` directive forces MASM to assume that a 32-bit program is running and not to switch to 32-bit every time. In this case, you must explicitly tell the assembler to use 16-bit segments, so it will assume that the code will execute in 16-bit mode:

```
STACK   SEGMENT   PARA STACK 'STACK' USE16
...
DSEG    SEGMENT   PARA PUBLIC 'DATA' USE16
...
CSEG    SEGMENT   PARA PUBLIC 'CODE' USE16
...
```

Memory addresses continued to be formed by combining a 16-bit segment part and a 16-bit offset part. A 'RETF' (`PROC FAR') fetches two 16-bit values from the stack and jumps there.

Change

```
PUSH DS           ; Put return seg. addr on stack
MOV EAX,0         ; Clear a register EAX
PUSH EAX          ; Put zero return address on stack
```

to

```
PUSH DS           ; Put PSP seg. addr on stack
MOV AX,0          ; Clear a register AX
PUSH AX           ; Put zero return address on stack
```

Segment addresses remain 16-bit. The 32-bit EAX therefore has a different operand size.

Change

```
MOV EAX,DSEG        ;Initialize DS
MOV DS,AX
```

to

```
MOV AX,DSEG         ;Initialize DS
MOV DS,AX
```

You generally cannot use different operand sizes (16-bit and 32-bit) in the same instruction.

Change

```
XCHG EAX,BX         ; Swap values of EAX and EBX
```

to

```
XCHG EAX,EBX        ; Swap values of EAX and EBX
```

It is possible to switch to full 32-bit operation (protected mode) for a short time during 16-bit operation (MS-DOS) but this is very complicated and error-prone and not recommended.

```
JL  .SWAPSUB        ; If EBX is greater than EAX, jump to SWAPSUB
JL  .NOSWAP         ; If ''                     , jump past other sub section
```

will not do what you expect. `JL` (jump if less) jumps after a **signed** comparison. So, 0xDEADBEEF (negative) will be less than 0x1FEDBEEF (positive). In this case, EAX and EBX will be swapped wrong, the SUB will result in a negative number and the DIFF will be wrong. BTW, the second `JL` will never jump, you meant `JNL` (jump if not less). `CMP` performs an **unsigned** comparison as well. So you can do a jump after an unsigned comparison with `JB` (jump if below). It is enough to use only one conditional jump (JNB - jump if not below), which may skip over the next instruction.

Change

```
JL  .SWAPSUB        ; If EBX is greater than EAX, jump to SWAPSUB
JL  .NOSWAP         ; If ''                     , jump past other sub section
```

to

```
JNB .NOSWAP         ; If EAX not below EBX, skip over .SWAPSUB
```

After `SUB EAX,EBX` the difference is in `EAX`, not `EBX`.

An example that makes use of the possibilities of MASM 5.1 and higher:

```
.MODEL SMALL, C                 ; 'C' also enables local labels and variables in MASM 5.1
.386                            ; Enable features of the i386 processor
.STACK 1000h                    ; Reserve space for stack and initialize stack pointer

.DATA
    X1          DD  1FEDBEEFh       ; 535674607
    X2          DD  0DEADBEEFh      ; 3735928559
    SUM         DD  ?
    DIFF        DD  ?
    SUM_STR     DB 16 DUP ('$')
    DIFF_STR    DB 16 DUP ('$')
    S           DB "SUM: $"
    D           DB "DIFF: $"
    CrLf        DB 13, 10, '$'

.CODE
OUR_PROG PROC

;  -------------------------------------------------------------
;  Initialize the data segment address
         MOV AX, @DATA          ; Initialize DS
         MOV DS, AX

;  -------------------------------------------------------------
;  Perform the addition
;
         MOV EAX, X1            ; Load 32 bit variable in X1 to reg EAX
         MOV EBX, X2            ; Load 32 bit variable in X2 to reg EBX
         ADD EAX, EBX           ; Add data in registers AX and BX, store in EAX

         MOV SUM, EAX           ; Store the result at mem loc SUM

;  -------------------------------------------------------------
;  Perform the subtraction
        MOV EAX, X1             ; Reload first word to reg EAX

        CMP EAX, EBX            ; Compare values of X1 and X2 stored in registers EAX and EBX
        JNB SHORT @F
        XCHG EAX, EBX           ; Swap values of EAX and EBX
        @@:
        SUB EAX, EBX            ; Subtract EBX from EAX
        MOV DIFF, EAX           ; Store the result at mem loc DIFF

;  -------------------------------------------------------------
;  Display the stuff

        MOV EAX, SUM            ; "SUM: 4271603166"
        LEA DI, SUM_STR
        CALL eax2dec
        LEA DX, S
        MOV AH, 9               ; http://www.ctyme.com/intr/rb-2562.htm
        INT 21h
        LEA DX, SUM_STR
        INT 21h
        LEA DX, CrLf
        Int 21h

        MOV EAX, DIFF           ; "DIFF: 3200253952"
        LEA DI, DIFF_STR
        CALL eax2dec
        LEA DX, D
        MOV AH, 9               ; http://www.ctyme.com/intr/rb-2562.htm
        INT 21h
        LEA DX, DIFF_STR
        INT 21h
        LEA DX, CrLf
        Int 21h

;  -------------------------------------------------------------
;  Exit the program

        MOV AX, 4C00h           ; Exit with code 0
        INT 21h                 ; Call MSDOS
OUR_PROG ENDP

;  -------------------------------------------------------------
;  Convert an integer in EAX to a decimal ASCII string

eax2dec PROC                    ; ARG EAX DWORD, DI: offset of string
LOCAL Regs[4]:DWORD

    IF (@Version EQ 510)        ; Bug in MASM 5.1: Wrong offset with `Regs`
        mov [bp-16], eax        ; Preserve some registers
        mov [bp-12], ebx
        mov [bp-8], ecx
        mov [bp-4], edx
    ELSE
        mov [Regs+0], eax
        mov [Regs+4], ebx
        mov [Regs+8], ecx
        mov [Regs+12], edx
    ENDIF

        xor cl, cl              ; Counter
        mov ebx, 10             ; Base 10
    @@:
        xor edx,edx             ; Clear EDX for division
        div ebx                 ; EAX/10 remainder EDX (eff. DL)
        push dx                 ; Onto the stack to get it later LIFO
        inc cl                  ; Increment counter
        test eax, eax           ; Anything more to divide?
        jnz @B                  ; Yes - jump to the @@ before
    @@:
        pop ax                  ; Get back the remainders LIFO
        or al, 30h              ; Convert to ASCII
        mov [di], al            ; Store it
        inc di                  ; Pointer to ASCII string
        dec cl                  ; Decrement pointer
        jnz @B                  ; If remainders left, jump to the @ before

        mov BYTE PTR [di], '$'  ; Terminator for INT 21h/09h

    IF (@Version EQ 510)        ; Bug in MASM 5.1: Wrong offset with `Regs`
        mov eax, [bp-16]        ; Restore some registers
        mov ebx, [bp-12]
        mov ecx, [bp-8]
        mov edx, [bp-4]
    ELSE
        mov eax, [Regs+0]
        mov ebx, [Regs+4]
        mov ecx, [Regs+8]
        mov edx, [Regs+12]
    ENDIF

        ret                     ; RET: DI points to the terminating '$'
eax2dec ENDP

;**********************************************************
END OUR_PROG                    ; END of source &  entry point
```